# pre-commit: Missing required key: name will local hook

Tags: pre-commit-hook, requirements.txt, pre-commit.com

I'm trying to set up a custom `repo: local` hook with `pre-commit` and running into an error message that I don't understand

My steps:

1. From `C:\Python\monorepo\project1\project1_app\` (in PyCharm terminal):

```
pre-commit install
```

2. Create the following file: `C:\Python\monorepo\.pre-commit-config.yaml`:

```
-   repo: local
    hooks:
    -   id: pre-commit
```

3. Edited `C:\Python\monorepo\.git\hooks\pre-commit`:

```
pip freeze > requirements_check.txt
cmp --silent requirements_check.txt requirements.txt

if [ $? -gt 0 ]; 
then
  echo "There are packages in the env not in requirements.txt"
  echo "Aborting commit"
  rm requirements_check.txt
  exit 1
fi

rm requirements_check.txt
exit 0
```

4. From `C:\Python\monorepo\project1\project1_app\` ran

```
pre-commit run --all-files
```

I want to get this running without an error (once I know the basic config setup is correct I can tweak the script for my needs), but I am currently getting an error as follows:

```
An error has occurred: InvalidConfigError: 
==> File .pre-commit-config.yaml
==> At Config()
==> At key: repos
==> At Repository(repo='local')
==> At key: hooks
==> At Hook(id='pre-commit')
=====> Missing required key: name
Check the log at C:\Users\myusername\.cache\pre-commit\pre-commit.log
```

I also tried adding the "name" argument to the .pre-commit.config.yaml file, running "pre-commit clean" and retrying "pre-commit run -all-files", but I still get the same error:

```
repos:
-   repo: local
    hooks:
    -   id: pre-commit
    -   name: pre-commit
```

Can someone help with my pre-commit setup/config so I can avoid this error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the error message is telling you that your yaml:

```
repos:
-   repo: local
    hooks:
    -   id: pre-commit
    -   name: pre-commit
```

makes a list of two dictionaries under `hooks` when you want to add the `name` key to the first dictionary

you'll also need `entry` and `language` and you will probably want `pass_filenames: false` too, but I'll let you figure that part out!

```yaml
repos:
-   repo: local
    hooks:
    -   id: pre-commit
        name: pre-commit
        entry: path/to/script.sh
        language: script
        pass_filenames: false
```

---

disclaimer: I wrote pre-commit

Comment: Thank you so much for the very helpful answer - it worked.
When I wrote this, I was using a "how to make bug report" video on Youtube - I've just realised it was yours - thank you for that too!!

Comment: I'm want to use python not bash to run "pip freeze > requirements.txt" before committing to git? Is it possible?

Comment: I've tried a lot of variations of settings in the ".pre-commit-config.yaml" and 'pre-commit"  but I've not been able to get requirements.txt to update.